# Alter appearance of an HTML link depending on the device its viewed on (computer vs phone, etc)?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've recently replaced the stock buttons on my google sites website with iframe HTML links that are whited out until you hover over them, revealing the text. It looks great for a computer but less so for anything without a cursor, where you can't see the text until you click on it, and then it's too late.

```
<body>
<p>
<a href="link" style="color:white">button</a>
</p>
</body>
<style>
a:link { color: white;
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none; }
a:active { text-decoration: none; }
p {
  font-size: 30px;
}
p {
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}
p {
margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
```

I was wondering if there's any way for the buttons to detect which type of device is viewing the page and use/not use the hover mechanic accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the `hover` media query for that.

For Desktop and any not touch related devices which supports the hover event, you could simply use this:

```css
@media (hover:hover) {
  a:link { color: white;
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none; }
a:active { text-decoration: none; }
}
```

and for any touch device:

```css
a:link {
 color: <your-color>
etc.
etc.
}
```

For better understanding, here is the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover) docs about `hover`.